# if a = number through number quest

Tags: if-statement, lua

I was wondering if lua "roblox", if statment has a way to go through....
well let me just show you.

`local a = some.object.value
if a == 5 or a == 6 or a == 7 ................. goes on for a long time.`

looking for a short cut. kinda like

`if a <= 2000 then "some code" end`

but this needs to start at like 5. Instead of 1 

`if a == 5 "through" 2000 then BLA end`

Also i know i can use a for loop to do the trick but i was just wondering if there was a way to do it without for loop?
I have googled lua wiki and looked around but i could not find anything. :( It is probably do to i don't know what this type of thing would be called.

Comment: what about if a>=5 and a<=2000 is this not what you want?

Comment: actually yes. That is what i was looking for. Thank you. I didn't think to use "and". *Facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Just formulate your condition in English:

If your number is in the interval 5-2000, number is greater than or equal 5 and number is  smaller than or equal 2000.

Now translate this to Lua

```
number >= 5 and number <=2000
```

If you're dealing with integer numbers only you may of course also use `number > 4 and number < 2001`

See [Lua Reference Manual 3.4.4: Relational Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.4) and
[Lua Reference Manual 3.4.5: Logical Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5)

If the number is in the interval both conditions will be `true`. `true and true` is `true`.
If any of the conditions is `false` either because your number is smaller 5 or greater 2000 it evaluates to `false` as both `false and true` and `true and false` evaluate to `false`.

In an if statement:

```
if number >= 5 and number <= 2000 then
-- do something
end
```